# Android how can i call button.isPressed() in a work thread

Tags: android, multithreading, button

I'm new with Android. I'm trying to do a separate thread (SenderThread). That thread is intent to send a string each 200ms in a UDP socket when a button is pressed.

So my question is how can I do something like:

```
if(myButton.isPressed())
{
}
```

but not in the UI thread?

---

If possible I would like start the SenderThread in OnCreate method in the UI Thread.

And then, in SenderThread, I want verify each 200ms if a button is pressed. If it is, I send a string via UDP, else I wait 200ms

Comment: Start the Thread when you click on the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `runOnUiThread` inside your `thread`

final Button myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.my_button);

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if(myButton.isPressed())
                    {
                    }

                }

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create some boolean parameter like this :

```
private boolean isButtonClicked = false;
```

Then in your `onClick()` method make `isButtonClicked = true;`

And now in your thread you can check is the button clicked :

```
if (isButtonClicked) {
    // button is clicked
} else {
    // button is not clicked
}
```

Comment: You need to make it `volatile` or use a `AtomicBoolean`. Otherwise it won't work